# Stop the execution of a function when a button is clicked in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, event-handling, onclick

I have an ASP.NET application in which I have a function that runs on a button click event, all I need is to have another button which when clicked the function that is running should stop executing. I have added the sample code. Can someone please help me on this? Thanks

```
protected void btnCreateSites_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  GenerateSites("CPM");
}

static void GenerateSites(string siteName)
{
  //perform some complex operation here
}

protected void btnStopExecute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //stop the execution of the GenerateSites() function when this button is clicked.
}
```

Comment: If you expect people to help you with your code, don't you think that it would be a good idea to post your code so people could see it?

Answer (score 1):

The first click event needs to launch a separate thread to run the process and store the reference to that thread somewhere.  The second click event will get the reference of that thread, if it still exists, and call abort.

That's the simple way.  Add some code to your question for an answer that is better suited to what you are trying to achieve.